# how to size and fill malloc array in C with bits

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

I think to initialize an array of size n filled with ints would be:

```
int *ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int))
```

To fill array ptr with numbers from 0 to n would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j< n; j++){
        ptr[j] = j;
}
```

Now I actually have an input array of size n, with random values that can be represented up to 16 bits. I think this means that there can be numbers valued up to 65,535?

I need to sort the input array using counting sort so I need to create a new array.

Does this mean instead of the n I used before for the size of ptr array, I replace it with 65,535 so that every possible value can fit in my array?

Comment: No, you don't typically create an intermediate array that has as many elements as the maximum possible value in the input set. Either you sort in place, or you create a second array that's the same length as the first array. But ... please clarify what the "fill with bits" part of your question is all about.

Comment: Why do you need an array to hold 65,535 elements?

Comment: Would you use the same mechanism if you had an array of 10-character strings?

Comment: If you want to sort an array, take a look at [qsort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3p.html)

Comment: @Kayla I was told the maximum number of bits needed to represent a value would be 16 bits, so I thought that meant 65,535 would be the biggest possible value inn the input array. Im trying to do count sort so I have to use a second array.

Comment: So, for sorting e.g. 17 values you want to allocate memory for an array of 65,536 values? That is extremely inefficient wrt memory consumption. Do you have any really good reason not to do in-place sorting with one of the common sorting algorithms?

Comment: If you want/need to sort the array in one pass then you would need an array of 65536 (not 65535, you need to be able to count values 0 to 65535). However, if you can sort the array in batches, then you would need only need an array that can hold the values in each batch. For example, you could sort the array in batches of 16. You would sort for the values 0-15 in the first batch, then 16-29 in the second batch, ..., up to the values 65520-65536 in the 4096th batch. In this case, the counting array would be of length 16. Of course, the size of the batch is up to you.

Comment: @Gerhardh I was told it has to be counting sort so I can later graph the runtime in comparison with other types of sorts. I am given input array with number of elements, n, and the maximum number of bits needed to represent a value which is 16. So like you said lets say I have 17 values to sort and allocate space for. I think  I can have numerical values up to 65,535? If I was using python I would create an array with 65,535 spaces but im not sure how to approach this in C with malloc.

Comment: @GerhardhWould I do: (int*)malloc(65536 * sizeof(int)) which I think means 65536 entries for ints in an array or (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(65536)) which means array of same size as input but each entry can store a value up to 65536. Am I making sense

Comment: The malloc doesn't depend on `n` at all, only on the maximum index you will use with it. You have determined the maximum index to be 65536.

Comment: If there can never be more than 255 copies of the same number in the list, you could reduce the memory some by using `unsigned char* ptr = malloc(65536*sizeof(*ptr));`. (Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C.)

Comment: @aschepler unless you know the maximum `n` there's no way to know what the maximum count will be.

Answer (score 0):

Counting sort is where the keys (in this case, numbers) are placed into buckets. The buckets contain *frequency* of keys that are in their range. This is in much the way as a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). In the case where the buckets have just one key (as is your case), you can reconstruct the original keys by generating the key of the bucket times the frequency.

It's confusing to have the range be `[0, 65,536)` and the domain be `[0, n)`. Perhaps a range of fruits would be clearer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FRUITS X(banana), X(pear), X(apple), X(kiwi), X(pomegranate), X(mango)
#define X(n) n
enum fruits { FRUITS };
#undef X
#define X(n) #n
static const char *const fruit_name[] = { FRUITS };
#undef X

int main(void) {
    enum fruits nu,
        fruits[] = { banana, apple, kiwi, pear, kiwi, banana, mango };
    size_t n,
        freq[sizeof fruit_name / sizeof *fruit_name] = { 0 };

    /* `O(n)` to go though `fruits` and make `freq`. */
    for(n = 0; n < sizeof fruits / sizeof *fruits; n++) freq[fruits[n]]++;

    /* `O(n)` to rebuild `fruits` from `freq` in order. */
    for(n = 0, nu = 0; nu < sizeof fruit_name / sizeof *fruit_name; nu++) {
        size_t iter = 0;
        printf("%s\t%zu\n", fruit_name[nu], freq[nu]);
        for(iter = 0; iter < freq[nu]; iter++) fruits[n++] = nu;
    }

    /* `O(n)` to display. */
    for(n = 0; n < sizeof fruits / sizeof *fruits; n++)
        printf("%s\n", fruit_name[fruits[n]]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this case, `int *ptr` is `freq[]`. It starts `freq[j] = 0`, not `freq[j] = j`. Note that the frequencies are never negative, in this case I've used a `size_t`.

If you require a large range of `freq`, than you should be thinking of dynamic memory allocation because the danger of stack overflow. How many frequencies can fit into one bin depends not on the range of fruit, (in your case, 16-bits,) but on `n`, the size of your list.